# What's the difference between issuing a query with or without a "begin" and "commit" command in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

As title say, it is possible to issue a query on psql with a "begin", query, and "commit".

What I want to know is what happens if I don't use a "begin" command?

Comment: postgresql#: create table t1(t int);

Comment: postgresql#:begin;
postgresql# create table t1(i int);
postgresql# commit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some database engine will allow you to execute modifications (`INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`) without an open transaction. It's basically assumed that you have an instant `BEGIN / COMMIT` around each of your instructions, which is a bad practice in case something goes wrong in a batch of many instructions.

You can still make a `SELECT`, but no `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` without a `BEGIN` to enforces the good practice. That way, if something goes wrong, a `ROLLBACK` is instantly executed, canceling all your modifications as if they never existed.

Using a transaction around a batch of various `SELECT` will guarantee that the data you get for each `SELECT` matches the same version of the database at the instant you open the transaction depending on your `ISOLATION` level.

Please read this for more information :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-start-transaction.html

and

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Comment: In the default isolation level (read committed), issuing multiple ``SELECT``s will **not** necessarily give you the same data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `BEGIN/COMMIT`, it's the same as wrapping each individual query in a `BEGIN/COMMIT` block.  You can use `BEGIN/COMMIT` to group multiple queries into a single transaction.  A few reasons you might want to do so include

- Updating multiple tables at the same time.  For instance, usually when you delete a record you also want to delete other rows that reference it.  If you do this in the same transaction, nothing will ever be able to reference a row that's already been deleted.
- You want to be able to revert some changes if something goes wrong later.  Suppose you're writing some user inputted data to multiple tables.  At some point you realize that some of it isn't formatted properly.  You probably wouldn't want to insert any of it, so you should wrap the entire operation in a transaction.
- If you want to ensure the data you're updating hasn't been updated while you're writing to it.  Suppose I'm adding $10 to a bank account from two separate connections.  I want to add $20 in total - I don't want one of the `UPDATE`s to clobber the other.

Postgres gives you the first two of these by default.  The last one would require a higher [transaction isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html), and makes your query run the risk of raising a serialization error.  Transaction isolation levels are a fairly complicated topic, so if you want more info on them the best place to go is the documentation.